# Sum of rectangles in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a code which doesnt work the way I want to. The problem is i need a sum of all rctangles from a picture as below.

My code:

```
imH = size(I, 1);
imW = size(I, 2);


windowWidth = 30;
windowHeight = 30;

step = 1;
for r = 1:step:imH - windowHeight + 1
    for c = 1:step:imW - windowWidth + 1


        Win = I(r:r + windowHeight - 1, c:c + windowWidth - 1, :);

        post =[c r windowHeight windowWidth];
```

I think I lack sum here

```
    %stop = waitforbuttonpress; 


    subplot(121); imshow(I); title 'Image';
    hold on;  

    rectangle('Position', pos, 'EdgeColor', 'r');

    hold off;

    subplot (122); imshow(W); title 'ooo';
    drawnow;
    pause(0.0000001);



    end 

end
```

Everything works great but I need to sum separately every rectangle values

Comment: Isn't that what you are doing? You are looping through your window and sum  `Nh` and `Nd` separately as far as I can see. You might need to clarify your question a bit.

Comment: I'm sorry! I meant separately Nh and Nd because I need sum Nh from all slides and sumNd from all slides. Now I only get Nh and Nd for one slide.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. It's good that you have added code but maybe you could add pseudo code or something to show what you actually want.

Comment: I edited my question. I don't know what's wrong with me that I can't explain this simple thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add `&` in the 1st and 2nd rgb intervals as below:

```
matchNh = (R > 45 & R < 180) & (G > 50 & G < 185) & (B > 160 & B < 215);  
matchNd = (R > 40 & R < 115) & (G > 6 & G < 80) & (B > 10 & B < 75);
```

Then you are doing right to count the nonzero pixels i.e.

```
Nh = nnz(matchNh);
Nd = nnz(matchNd);
```

If you want to use for more than one image , then you can use another for loop outside the two for loops e.g.

```
imgnames = dir('*.jpg');    % get list of jpg images in current directory
NN = length(imgnames)
%sliding window size
windowWidth = 64;
windowHeight = 64;

%step
step = 64;

Nh = 0;
Nd = 0;

for ii = 1 : NN
    I = imread(imgnames(ii).name);
    % your code i.e. two for loops as you have written above
    imH = size(I, 1);
    imW = size(I, 2);


    for r = 1:step:imH - windowHeight + 1
        for c = 1:step:imW - windowWidth + 1

        %sliding window value
        W = I(r:r + windowHeight - 1, c:c + windowWidth - 1, :);

        pos =[c r windowHeight windowWidth];

        R = W(:,:,1);
        G = W(:,:,2);
        B = W(:,:,3);

        % RGB intervals for every sliding window
        matchNh = (R > 45 & R < 180) & ...
                  (G > 50 & G < 185) & ...        
                 (B > 160 & B < 215);  

        matchNd = (R > 40 & R < 115) & ...
                  (G > 6 & G < 80) & ...
                  (B > 10 & B < 75);
        Nh = Nh + nnz(matchNh);
        Nd = Nd + nnz(matchNd);


        end
    end
    PIc = Nd / (Nh + Nd)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually the code works good and it counts the nonzeros well but for one slide I need to count the sum of all slides.

Comment: I have modified the answer to sum the Nh and Nd for all the jpg images in a certain directory.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're the best!